# Converter pointer em string

Tags: delphi

Olá,

Eu gostaria de saber como posso efetuar a conversão de pointer para string, pois quando tento usar o Pointer em uma MessageBoxA por exemplo, ela me volta o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem de erro]

Estou tentando exibir a mensagem assim:

```
 MessageBoxA(0, Pointer ,nil,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

O `Pointer` e a *definição de ponteiro* no Delphi, um tipo de dado. Um ponteiro guarda o endereço de uma variável que esta na memória, e através dele se pode acessar o valor da variável que o ponteiro esta apontando.

Exemplo, acessando uma variável string:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pExemplo: Pointer;
  vStr, r: string;
begin
  vStr := 'exemplo ponteiro';

  pExemplo := @vStr;//pExemplo recebe o endereço de vStr.

  r := string(pExemplo^);//Aqui é feita a conversão da variável para string. 

  ShowMessage(r);
end;
```

A variável `r` recebeu o valor de `vStr` através do ponteiro `pExemplo`.

Mais sobre ponteiros em Delphi [aqui](http://blog.joaomorais.com.br/2008/08/23/ponteiros.html).
Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Após procurar um pouco mais, descobri que devo primeiramente transforma-lo em Integer ( Integer(Pointer) ) e depois converte-la em string ( IntToStr( Int ) )

Código ficaria assim: `IntToStr(integer( Pointer ))`

Comment: Esta expressão esta errada, não da para converter o *Pointer*, vc tem que converter a variável do tipo Pointer.

Comment: Somente não me expressei direito, mas você está certo.

Answer (score 0):

Deixe o compilador ajudar você. Use `PChar`, é o jeito mais seguro e facil de fazer.

```
int WINAPI MessageBox(
  _In_opt_ HWND    hWnd,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  _In_     UINT    uType
);
```

`MessageBox(0, PChar('Teste'), PChar('Titulo'), MB_OK);`

Entretanto, na maioria dos casos eu utilizaria:

Em Primeiro Lugar:

```
uses Dialogs;
ShowMessage(const Msg: String);
```

Em segundo Lugar

```
uses Forms;
Application.MessageBox(Text, Caption: PChar; Flags: LongInt = MB_OK);
```

Se um dia você migrar sua aplicação para `Unicode`, você não vai querer chamar a função `MessageBoxA`, pois se sua string for unicode (provavelmente será se você declarar sua variável como `string`), seu código poderá falhar.